# Podfile `inhibit_all_warnings!` no longer works for Swiftlint

Tags: swift, xcode

It's 2023 (Xcode 14.2, Swiftlint 0.50.3) and what used to work a few months ago for suppressing Swift warnings no longer works. I want to focus on warnings for my own project, not see the 450 warnings for Swift code that I don't control. Three solutions don't work :

1. Podfile was containing `inhibit_all_warnings!` but this no longer works ;
2. A similar SO question from long ago had an answer suggesting `config.build_settings['SWIFT_SUPPRESS_WARNINGS'] = "YES"` but this appears to have no effect either ;
3. Going to the Pods project file's "Build Settings" and searching for `inhibit_all_warnings` finds a setting that is not even set to Yes ! But also, setting it to Yes has no effect !

So it seems that there are at least two levels at which it's being ignored : Pod no longer can put it in the Xcode project, and the Xcode project no longer can make Swiftlint use this option. I don't have an older Xcode and/or Swiftlint around to compare exactly with how it used to be. I have tried everything to make sure Xcode picks up any changes beyond just `pod install` : exiting Xcode before the pod install, deleting the `Pods` folder in case it makes any difference. And of course I do `Product > Clear All Issues` and `Product > Clean Build Folder` before any rebuild.

It would be much less irritating if all those warnings in "Issue Navigator" were in a subtree labelled `Pods` instead of being mixed with everything else alphabetically by basename of each file, but I don't see any way to organise issues this way, nor to filter them out (as the scopes do in the "Search" tab).

(I can't seem to run Swiftlint standalone on this project ; this is a separate issue, but I mean that I can't run standalone as a solution to this Pods problem, nor even for troubleshooting)

Comment: pod version 1.11.3

Comment: I don't think SwiftLint looks into project build settings at all because its behavior is guided by its configuration file (.swiftlint.yml) and/or command line arguments. You need to make sure to exclude the Pods directory from the SwiftLint's scope in the config file (for example, using the `excluded:` option or by explicitly specifying the paths to lint with the `included:` option).

Comment: Ok, but in my `.swiftlint.yml`, I already have `excluded:` `  - Pods`.

Comment: Perhaps SwiftLint isn't reading the configuration file then. Try to add a line with just a colon in it (`:`) at the beginning of `.swiftlint.yml` and see if it errors out. If it doesn't, perhaps you need to explicitly pass the path to the config with the `--config` argument.

Comment: added the lone colon at the beginning, got this extra message that I wasn't getting (and several times more other warnings than until now) :
`warning: YML Parsing Error: 1:1: error: parser: while parsing a block mapping in line 1, column 1`
`did not find expected key:`
`:`
`^ – Falling back to default configuration`

... so, `.swiftlint.yml` is being read.

Comment: Great, so it means that SwiftLint does indeed read to config file. At this point I'm out of guesses why it still lints the Pods directory. Are you sure these warnings come from SwiftLint and not from the Swift compiler?

Comment: The names of warning types in parentheses match those specified in my `.swiftlint.yml`... so this looks a lot like SwiftLint and not the compiler.

Comment: I just made a workaround in the `included:` section that removes `- .` and adds `- "*.swift"` and all the specific folders that contain my Swift sources. It just seems to be ignoring `- Pods` in the `excluded:` section. Ok, got it, it's because I had moved an old Pods installation from `Pods` to `Pods.bak`, which wasn't excluded, but XCode only shows the basename in the list of issues, no folder name. Also the list of files actually compiled with in `*.xcodeproj` is not being passed to `swiftlint`... is there a way to do that instead of `included: - .` ?

Comment: And as this problem wasn't what it seemed at first, and seems to be of limited usefulness to other users, should it stay on SO ?